# PyQt4 - convert list to QVector

Tags: list, type-conversion, pyqt4, qgis, qvector

How can I derive a `QVector` from a python list?

I tried

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  #... is QVector herein?
[...]
v=QVector()
for l in list:
    v.append(l)
```

The key problem is, that I want to use a method that expects `QVector` as input where passing a simple python list causes an error. And furthermore `name 'QVector' is not defined`. Please refer to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212252/unexpected-bevaviour-of-qgslinevectorlayerdirector-makegraph-when-passing-li for details.

**UPDATE**
`QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR` gives me `'4.10.2'`, so this shouldn't be a version issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyQt has never wrapped the `QVector` class, and it's unlikely that there will ever be a reason for doing so.

The `QgsLineVectorLayerDirector.makeGraph` method is expecting a list of `QgsPoint` instances. So presumably either (1) the list you're passing in doesn't contain objects that are all of the right type, or (2) the `Qgs` library you're using is broken.